# Something better than event with single event handler for raising async method

Tags: c#, multithreading

At the moment to call a method on the thread pool and still get the exceptions if there are any I am using an event with a single event handler and call the event handler with `BeginInvoke()`.

Class A subscribes to the event from Class B. Class B doesn't know anything about Class A.

I can't help but have the feeling that this is the stupid hacky way to do this, so howdo you do it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to using the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) instead of `ThreadPool`, it has great [exception handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415.aspx) support.

> how do I inject the "reference" to the Method in Class A into Class B without giving class B a reference to Class A

You would need to update class `B` to take in the function either as a constructor parameter or as a property e.g.

```
public class A
{
    public void MethodToCall(string args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am class A - " + args);
    }
}

public class B
{
    public B(Action<string> action)
    {
        Method = action;
    }

    public Action<string> MethodToCall { get; private set; }
}
...
var a = new A();
var b = new B(a.MethodToCall);
a.MethodToCall("A"); // I am class A - A
b.MethodToCall("B"); // I am class A - B
```

Comment: Don't think that helps with the "subscription" part of the problem.

Comment: @Ben your re-inventing the wheel - The TPL was built for these types of situations. It has exception handling support so there is no need for custom events etc.

Comment: I guess what I am asking, is how to I inject the "reference" to the Method in Class A into Class B without giving class B a reference to Class A. At the moment I am subscribing to events in Class B. For instance I know that Method outline is always going to be `MethodToCall(string arg)` but I don't want to give Class B a reference to class A, only a reference to `ClassA.MethodToCall(string args)`

Comment: @Ben seems completely off from what your original question was...I have updated my question with an example of how to do what you want anyway.

Comment: Thanks!...`Action` is LINQ isn't it? Do you know how this would have been written in a pre-LINQ .NET version, purely out of interest.

Comment: @Ben no [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx) is part of the core framework. It's been there since .NET 2.0 - It's essentially just a generic delegate. You could re-write the above by declaring a new public delegate in class `B` i.e. `public delegate void MethodToCallDelegate(string args);` then replacing the constructor parameter/property to use `MethodToCallDelegate` rather than `Action<string>`...`Action<T>` is much preferred though.